# Laravel table joins

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to do some table joins and having some trouble.i need to  display
the customer’s complete name and title, item description, quantity ordered, for each item ordered after April 2000. i made a SQL script that works but i need to use Laravel ORM.

```
SELECT  `first_name`,`last_name`,o.order_id,`quantity`,`description`,`date_placed`
FROM `customer` c 
JOIN `order` o
  ON c.`customer_id` = o. `customer_id` 
JOIN `orderline` ol
  ON o.`order_id` = ol. `order_id` 
JOIN `item` i
  ON ol.`item_id` = i. `item_id`
WHERE `date_placed` > '2000-4-00';
```

I created 2 models for the tables "Customer", "Order"

here is my Customer model

```
public function orders(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Order','customer_id');
}
```

here is my order model

```
public function orderline(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Orderline','order_id');
}
```

right now i am able to get some of my data but i dont feel like this is a good way to go about

```
$customer = Customer::all();
foreach($customer as $input){
        $item = Customer::find($input->customer_id)->orders;
        $name = $input->title . ' ' . $input->first_name . ' ' . $input->last_name;

        $datePlaced = null;
        $orderID = null;
    foreach($item as $value){
        $orderID = $value->order_id;
        $datePlaced = $value->date_placed;
        $order = Order::find($value->order_id)->orderline;
    }
```

if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: what is the question? is there any error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to get all `Customer`s with their `Order`s and `OrderLine`s?

```
Customer::with(['order' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('date_placed', '>=', '2000-04-01')->with('orderline');
}])->get();
```

If you want to limit the columns on the relationships, you can...

```
Customer::with(['order' => function ($query) {
    $query->select(/* columns */)->where('date_placed', '>=', '2000-04-01')
          ->with(['orderline' => function ($query) {
              $query->select(/* columns here */);
          }]);
}])->get();
```

Just make sure if you specify the columns in the relationships, that you're selecting all of the foreign keys or related columns for each relationship.

Comment: Great. Check out some of the free Laracasts videos on Laravel and Eloquent. That will give you a good start to learning this stuff.